# How to draw transparent lines in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, transparent

I defined a canvas variable as a child so it can show up in the animation.  The following code is in a KeyFrame handler:

```
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
gc.setLineWidth(5);
gc.strokeLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);// randome numbers
```

With the animation going on, the lines filled up the window.  I wanted to remove lines.  I can use `gc.clearRect(...)` which removes the whole canvas.  But what if I just want to make a segment of line disappear?  I used

```
gc.setStroke(Color.TRANSPARENT);
gc.strokeLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
```

but it doesn't do anything.  I know how to do it in Swing, I used `g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getIstance(...,...))` to do it.  What is the corresponding way to make pixels transparent in JavaFX?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?